# Getting error: incomparable types: char and String

Tags: java

Is there a way to convert a string array into a char array. Currently I have the code:

```
String[] alphabet = {"a","A","b","B","c","C","d","D","e","E","f","F","g","G","h","H","i","I","j","J","k","K","l","L","m","M","n","N","o","O","p","P","q","Q","r","R","s","S","t","T","u","U","v","V","w","W","x","X","y","Y","z","Z"};
    char[] charArray = alphabet.toCharArray();
```

Currently this gives me the error message:

```
error: cannot find symbol
        char[] charArray = alphabet.toCharArray();
```

Comment: Why do you need to use a `String` array at all?

Comment: you need a string not an array of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will convert string array to char array

```
String[] alphabet = {"a","A","b","B","c","C","d","D","e","E","f","F","g","G","h","H","i","I","j","J","k","K","l","L","m","M","n","N","o","O","p","P","q","Q","r","R","s","S","t","T","u","U","v","V","w","W","x","X","y","Y","z","Z"};
String s = "";
for (String n:alphabet)
    s+= n;
char[] c = s.toCharArray();
```

Comment: @Aominè Actually, the question was to get an array of char from array of strings. I know this typecasting can be avoided but this was the question

Answer (score 3):

you need to use `String` object because [`toCharArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()) is a method of [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class

```
String alphabet = "aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ";
char[] charArray = alphabet.toCharArray();
```

Just in case if you still want a String array , just split on empty String

```
String [] arr = alphabet.split(""); // your String array
```